# Highchart Donut chart not circular

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highchart to create a donut chart with a rounded corner. Unfortunately, the chart is not fully circular.
[image]

```js
var data2 = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Positve",
                "y": 50,
                "color": "#2CA02C",
                "sliced": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Negative",
                "y": 25,
                "color": "#B23333",
                "sliced": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Neutral",
                "y": 25,
                "color": "#E5CF73",
                "sliced": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
    window.mychart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
          plotShadow: false,
        },
      credits: {
          enabled: false
      },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '100%',
              borderWidth: 10,
              borderColor: null,
              slicedOffset: 6,
              dataLabels: {
                  connectorWidth: 0,
                  enabled: false
              }
            }
        },
      title: {
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            floating: true,
            text: ''
      },
      legend: {
      },
        series: data2,
    });
```

Here is the jsfiddle link to it:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shadab_faiz/bdoL9zty/16/)

Comment: The necessary code to reproduce the issue must be included in the question itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My bad. I've added the code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one point can be sliced, so use data without the sliced property or set `slicedOffset` to 0.

```
"data": [{
    "name": "Positve",
    "y": 50,
    "color": "#2CA02C"
  },
  {
    "name": "Negative",
    "y": 25,
    "color": "#B23333"
  },
  {
    "name": "Neutral",
    "y": 25,
    "color": "#E5CF73"
  }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1usgc4a6/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data.sliced

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.slicedOffset

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but  that series of chart needs to be touching each other at the end, not overlapping.

Comment: Hi @Shadab Faiz, Ok, I didn't know your design assumptions. You can add mocked points with transparent color. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7h65kdx8/

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for.